# How to get the size of all local variables, when not using a naked function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function, assembly

How do I get the size of all local variables (how much is my stack shifted in the prolog), in a non-naked function?

In a naked function, I would be able to use the __LOCAL_SIZE symbol.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: So I can inspect arguments provided earlier in the function chain.

Comment: what for? Are you trying to get a stack trace? C++ isn't the language for this kind of reflection.

Comment: Yes, im backtracking the stack, and I managed it with a small prolog inline asm "hack".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StackWalk64 in dbghelp.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do a full stack walk.  EBP and ESP are part of the structure that describes each stackframe.